# Extract email from field using Oracle Regexp

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I want to get e-mail formed texts in a field. I have tried sql below but no luck. See [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/23829). Removing ^ and $ from regexp not working too.

```
WITH TEST_DATA AS (
  SELECT 'foo@gmail.com' AS EMAIL FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'mail foo@gmail.com' FROM DUAL UNION ALL           
  SELECT 'mail foo@gmail.com sent' FROM DUAL UNION ALL                
  SELECT 'foo@gmail.com sent count 23' FROM DUAL UNION ALL          
  SELECT 'mail already sent to foo@gmail.com and foo@hotmail.com' FROM DUAL UNION ALL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  SELECT 'foo@gmail.com sent count 23' FROM DUAL             
)SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(EMAIL,'^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$') MAIL
 FROM TEST_DATA;
```

Expected output for this dataset

```
foo@gmail.com 
foo@gmail.com 
foo@gmail.com 
foo@gmail.com 
foo@gmail.com, foo@hotmail.com 
foo@gmail.com
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You definitely want to remove the anchors for start of text and end of text (^$) because in this case you'll completely miss emails like `foo@bbc.co.uk`.  Also, I'm guessing here, but I think your regex will not pick emails like `firstname.lastname@enterprise.com`.  Email recognition in regex is incredibly hard, and prone to errors, I wish you luck.

Comment: thanks @MauriceReeves. it retrives both your samples.

Comment: Don't forget that foo+name@gmail.com is also a valid email.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to extract multiple mail ids in a single column, you can use `REGEXP_REPLACE` function.

Assuming all the ids in your data are valid ones,

```
REGEXP_REPLACE (EMAIL, '(\w+@\w+\.\w+ ?)|(.)', '\1')
```

This removes all other text except for mail ids that are separated by at least a space.

You can then remove any trailing spaces and add comma to separate multiple ids.

```
REPLACE (TRIM (REGEXP_REPLACE (EMAIL, '(\w+@\w+\.\w+ ?)|(.)', '\1')),
            ' ',
            ', ')
```

Example:

```
WITH TEST_DATA
     AS (SELECT 'foo@gmail.com' AS EMAIL FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'mail foo@gmail.com' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'mail foo@gmail.com sent to 123@zxc.com and qwe@rt.com' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'foo@gmail.com sent count 23 and asd@qwert.edu' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'mail already sent to foo@gmail.com and foo@hotmail.com' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'foo@gmail.com sent count 23' FROM DUAL)
SELECT REPLACE (TRIM (REGEXP_REPLACE (EMAIL, '(\w+@\w+\.\w+ ?)|(.)', '\1')),
                ' ',
                ', ')
          MAIL
  FROM TEST_DATA;

MAIL
-----------------------------
foo@gmail.com
foo@gmail.com
foo@gmail.com, 123@zxc.com, qwe@rt.com
foo@gmail.com, asd@qwert.edu
foo@gmail.com, foo@hotmail.com
foo@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 3):

You are close!
try this

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(EMAIL,'[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}') MAIL
```

edited:

Maybe this helps:

```
WITH TEST_DATA AS (
  SELECT 'foo@gmail.com' AS EMAIL FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'mail foo@gmail.com' FROM DUAL UNION ALL           
  SELECT 'mail foo@gmail.com sent' FROM DUAL UNION ALL                
  SELECT 'foo@gmail.com sent count 23' FROM DUAL UNION ALL          
  SELECT 'mail already sent to foo@gmail.com and foo@hotmail.com' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'foo@gmail.com sent count 23' FROM DUAL             
)SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(EMAIL,'[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}') MAIL,
        REGEXP_SUBSTR(EMAIL,'[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}',1,2) MAIL2
 FROM TEST_DATA
```

I don't see a way to report 'n' number of matches.  I also do not realize how to insert a comma and output into one column.  I would bet that if possible, the query will be become quite complex with multiple inner selects/finds/replaces occuring.  A better solution may be to return the original result to another language for parsing or to perform such parsing using pl/sql.

Another edit:

Here is what I meant regarding the inner selects. Exact solution to the asked question :-)

```
select CASE WHEN MAIL2 is not null THEN mail||', '||mail2 ELSE mail END as mail
from (
    WITH TEST_DATA AS (
      SELECT 'foo@gmail.com' AS EMAIL FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
      SELECT 'mail foo@gmail.com' FROM DUAL UNION ALL           
      SELECT 'mail foo@gmail.com sent' FROM DUAL UNION ALL                
      SELECT 'foo@gmail.com sent count 23' FROM DUAL UNION ALL          
      SELECT 'mail already sent to foo@gmail.com and foo@hotmail.com' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
      SELECT 'foo@gmail.com sent count 23' FROM DUAL             
    )SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(EMAIL,'[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}') MAIL,
            REGEXP_SUBSTR(EMAIL,'[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}',1,2) MAIL2
     FROM TEST_DATA
)
```

I also stubled upon this Oracle articale which discusses e-mail matching at point 8.  It might be worth a peek.
http://www.orafaq.com/node/2404

Comment: It's not generating expected output. all rows returns foo@gmail.com. Is it possible to get foo@hotmail.com too?

Comment: Not elegant solution @Michael Ford but it's very hard to get all matches just using sql. So this is the best we can :) Thank you.

Comment: Just be careful because this regex will also match foo@..com and
.@..com.  It's a really good regex, but you're still going to possibly run into some junk data.  The only thing I'd probably add are a \b at each end to specify word boundaries because it will also match something like .@..company but will just grab out to .comp, which isn't the intent of your extraction.

Comment: @MauriceReeves Does Oracle allow word boundary tokens?

Comment: @hkutluay  This regex:  [A-Z0-9._%+-]+@([A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,6}  should avoid the consecutive dot issue mentioned above

Comment: Ugh, apparently it doesn't.  What a shame.  Why would Oracle only implement *some* of the features of Perl regexes?  That's frustrating.